# Woocommerce Short_Description in Details Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm creating my new website with Wordpress and Woocommerce. I would like to display the short description in the order detail.

I found this code :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
```

But that shows me the description in home.

Is there a way to make it appear in the order detail?

Comment: I feel the need to say that Stack Overflow is not a "forum" but a fact based Q&A platform. Ongoing discussions of programming problems are not allowed as you will find on "forums".

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with a custom unction hooked in `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_single_excerpt_to_order_item', 10, 3 );
function add_single_excerpt_to_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product Id
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $product_id ); // Get the short description

    return $item_name . '<br><p class="item-description">' . $excerpt ; '</p>';
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works. It will display the short description in Order items below the item name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've tested the code and it works great. I do not know how to repay, can I make a donation to the site or something else? Thanks again

Comment: If this answer works for you, then upvote this answer and make this answer as correct. So that others can use this.