# WooCommerce Short_Description in details order before product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm using [Woocommerce Short_Description in Details Order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47915553/11987538)

Unfortunately, the short description of the product is displayed in second place.

1. Product name with link
2. Short product description
3. Design / (variants of products)
4. Article number (SKU NUMBER)

But I need the Short product description FIRST!

1. Short product description
2. Product name with link
3. Design / (variants of products)
4. Article number (SKU NUMBER)

How can I do this / what should the code be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Look into the Woocommerce templates and the filter hooks. That's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

self-help - problem solved

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_single_excerpt_to_order_item', 10, 3 );
function add_single_excerpt_to_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product Id
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $product_id ); // Get the short description

    return $excerpt . $item_name;
}
```