# Display product excerpt in WooCommerce order details table and sort order items based on that

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Currently I'm using [Woocommerce Short_Description in Details Order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47915553/11987538) answer code to show the product excerpt on WooCommerce checkout page:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_single_excerpt_to_order_item', 10, 3 );
function add_single_excerpt_to_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product Id
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $product_id ); // Get the short description

    return $excerpt . $item_name ;
}
```

---

Then I try to sort the order items alphabetically, based on the product excerpt. Via [How to sort WooCommerce order items alphabetically](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/sort-woocommerce-order-items-alphabetically/) i was able to write following code:

```php
/*
 * Filters the $order->get_items() method results to order all line items by
 * product name
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', function( $items, $order ) {

  uasort( $items, 
          function( $a, $b ) { 
            return strnatcmp( $a['excerpt'], $b['excerpt'] ); 
          }
        );

  return $items;

}, 10, 2 );
```

With this code I don't get any error messages, but I don't get the desired result either. Any advice how to sort excerpt by alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the short product description you can use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_item_name( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Get the product ID
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

    // Get the short description
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $product_id );

    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ($excerpt ) ) {
        return $excerpt . ' - ' . $item_name;
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 3 );
```

**Note:** because the `woocommerce_order_item_name` hook is executed on multiple pages (as well as WooCommerce email notifications) you could use [conditional tags](https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

---

Regarding sorting, `$a['excerpt']` does not exist, you can replace it with `get_the_excerpt( $a['product_id'] )`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_get_items( $items, $order, $types ) {
    // Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association
    uasort( $items, function( $a, $b ) {
        // String comparisons using a "natural order" algorithm
        return strnatcmp( get_the_excerpt( $a['product_id'] ), get_the_excerpt( $b['product_id'] ) ); 
    } );

    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_woocommerce_order_get_items', 10, 3 );
```